Digital potentiometer X9C104P with a Raspberry Pi 5
I've tried using a Raspberry Pi 5 to control a digital potentiometer X9C104P. I followed this wiring diagram:
Potentiometer (POT) - Raspberry Pi

INC: GPIO20
UD: GPIO21
Vh: 5V
Vss: GND
Vcc: 5V
CS: GPIO16
Vl: GND
Vw: LED



enter link description here
Implemented the provided code:
import tkinter as tk
import spidev

# Configuration du SPI (bus série)
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(1, 2)  # Bus SPI 1, périphérique 2 (CE2)
spi.max_speed_hz = 1000000  # Vitesse de communication (1 MHz)

# Fonction pour ajuster la position du curseur
def adjust_potentiometer(direction):
    current_position = spi.xfer2([0x00])[0]
    if direction == "up":
        new_position = min(current_position + 1, 127)
    elif direction == "down":
        new_position = max(current_position - 1, 0)
    else:
        return
    spi.xfer2([0x80 | new_position])

# Création de l'interface Tkinter
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Contrôle du Potentiomètre X9C104P")

# Boutons pour ajuster le potentiomètre
btn_up = tk.Button(root, text="Augmenter", command=lambda: adjust_potentiometer("up"))
btn_down = tk.Button(root, text="Diminuer", command=lambda: adjust_potentiometer("down"))

# Placement des boutons dans la fenêtre
btn_up.pack()
btn_down.pack()

# Boucle principale Tkinter
root.mainloop()

# Fermeture du bus SPI
spi.close()

However, the obtained result is that both buttons have the same effect: they increase the resistance, which decreases the brightness. Unfortunately, I couldn't manage to decrease the resistance.
Thank you for your help, I'm really stuck.

Where are your buttons defined?

btn_up = tk.Button(root, text="Augmenter", command=lambda: adjust_potentiometer("up"))
btn_down = tk.Button(root, text="Diminuer", command=lambda: adjust_potentiometer("down"))

yes, but where are they assigned to particular GPIO?

I utilized the SPI device: spi.open(1, 2) # SPI Bus 1, Device 2 (CE2).

There are multiple issues with this question. You are powering from 5V but Pi is 3.3V; Your connection is unclear and incomplete; it is unclear if you have enabled SPI; you are using a 100k POT which will only provide minuscule current; your code is incomplete (just for starters).

Try adding this:
define the following variable:
alt_position = current_position + 1

replace new_position variable definition in the "up" if statement in the function adjust_potentiometer
if not alt_position > 127:
  alt_position += 1
elif alt_position > 127:
  alt_position -= 1

and for new_position's "down" if statement:
if not alt_position < 0:
  alt_position -= 1
elif alt_position < 0:
  alt_position +=1

Comment if you have questions. Hope this helps!

like that : def adjust_potentiometer(direction):
current_position = spi.xfer2([0x00])[0]
global alt_position
if direction == "up":
    alt_position = current_position + 1
    if not alt_position > 127:
        alt_position += 1
    elif alt_position > 127:
        alt_position -= 1
elif direction == "down":
    alt_position = current_position - 1
    if not alt_position < 0:
        alt_position -= 1
    elif alt_position < 0:
        alt_position += 1
else:
    return
spi.xfer2([0x80 | alt_position])


Did you define alt_position outside of the function adjust_potentiometer?

On a side note, alt_position needs to be assigned in both cases as current_position + 1, or else the overall calculations you want to make will get distorted by fluctuating up and down.

it does not work

What comes out as an output? What error where?
